# Using both numeric and categorical variables to fit a decision tree using sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

While using onehotencoding for categorical variables in sklearn how do I use the sparse matrix generating along with my other numerical variables to fit a decision tree?
If i use OneHotEncoding to convert the categorical variables to a sparse matrix, how do i then combine this sparse matrix with the numerical variables in the original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

- [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.transform) with argument `categorical_features` indexing your features to encode (automatic combination of all your features)

  - The result is sparse by default (using `transform`) if you did not change `sparse=True`
- Or: stack those values onto your original ones when using *OneHotEncoder* just on a subset of variables:

  - `scipy.sparse.hstack((onehot, original))`
  - Where `onehot` will be of shape `(n_samples, ?` (depends on your featurs) and `original` will be of shape `(n_samples, ?`